# sed permission denied when using pam_exec with su

Tags: pam, su

I'm using pam_mount.so to automatically mount a CIFS share for users on an Ubuntu 14.04 client.

pam_mount uses a local conf in every users home directory. I'm running a bash script with pam_exec that updates the configuration file with the path to the CIFS share.

The end of my /etc/pam.d/common-session file looks like this:

```
session required    pam_unix.so 
session optional    pam_exec.so log=/var/log/pamexec /usr/local/bin/mdrive_add
session optional    pam_mount.so 
session optional    pam_ldap.so 
session optional    pam_systemd.so
```

When logging in with SSH or through the GUI, this works, the script is run before the mount, so the share is accessible.

However, when using su, the script fails, and the local user conf is not updated, so the mount fails too.

The error I receive when using su from [accountA] to [accountB] is:

```
/bin/sed: couldn't open temporary file /home/[accountB]/sednpoogQ: Permission denied
```

The line in the script that fails is this one:

`/bin/sed -i "s|\@S|${XSERVER}|g" /home/${PAM_USER}/.pam_mount.conf.xml`

I have tried running the script from ~/.profile and other places, this works flawlessly, but is not run before pam_mount.

So my question is, how can I get pam_exec to replace a string in a text file residing in a user's home directory when using su?

**Update**

Per the comments, I've tried 'sudo -u [accountb] -i' (after including @common-session in /etc/pam.d/sudo) and this does not return the same error, it works. However, it is not an acceptable solution, as I require su to work (and it causes a password prompt from pam_mount).

**Update2**

I've logged in with ssh, dumped env into a file and then I've logged in with ssh from another account, used su and dumped env to a file.

Comparing the two (account names replaced with accounta and accountb as in the question:

```
$ comm -3 <(sort ssh_list.txt ) <(sort su_list.txt)
    PASSWD_FD=0
    _PMT_DEBUG_LEVEL=0
    PWD=/home/[accounta]
PWD=/home/[accountb]
SHLVL=1
    SHLVL=2
    SSH_CLIENT=10.112.9.87 58090 22
SSH_CLIENT=10.112.9.87 58695 22
    SSH_CONNECTION=10.112.9.87 58090 10.80.0.68 22
SSH_CONNECTION=10.112.9.87 58695 10.80.0.68 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/13
    SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/14
    XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/10006
    XDG_SESSION_ID=6
XDG_SESSION_ID=7
```

**Update3**

Added the full script run by pam_exec (sensitive information replaced with placeholders):

```
#!/bin/bash
USERN=$PAM_USER
if grep -q @S /home/${USERN}/.pam_mount.conf.xml || grep -q @P /home/${USERN}/.pam_mount.conf.xml; then
    BASEDIR=`ldapsearch -LLL -H ldaps://dc.example.org:3269 -D "account@example.org" -b "DC=c,DC=sdu,DC=dk" -w [secretpw] "sAMAccountName=${USERN}" dn`;
    PREFIX="dn:: "
    BASEDIR=${BASEDIR#$PREFIX}
    PREFIX="dn: "
    BASEDIR=${BASEDIR#$PREFIX}
    BASEDIR=`echo $BASEDIR | tr -d ' '`
    if [[ $BASEDIR != *","* ]]
        then
               BASEDIR=`echo $BASEDIR | base64 --decode`
        fi
    BASEDIR=`echo $BASEDIR | tr -d ' \n' | awk -F "DC=" '{ st = index($0,"DC=");print substr($0,st+0)}'`;
    DOMAIN=`echo $BASEDIR | sed 's/,DC=/./g' | sed 's/DC=//'`;
    OUTPUT=`ping -c 1 -t 10 $DOMAIN | grep icmp`
    HOMEDIR='\\fallbackserver\share'
    if [[ -n "$OUTPUT" ]]
        then
            DC=`echo $OUTPUT| cut -d' ' -f 4`
            HOMEDIR=`ldapsearch -LLL -H ldaps://$DC:636 -D "account@example.org" -b "${BASEDIR}" -w [secretpw] "sAMAccountName=${USERN}" homeDirectory | grep homeDirectory | awk '{print $2}'`;
        fi
    CHOMEDIR=$(echo ${HOMEDIR} | sed 's/\\/\//g')

    XSERVER=`echo $CHOMEDIR | cut -f3 -d/`
    XPATH=`echo $CHOMEDIR | cut -f4- -d/`



    /bin/sed -i "s|\@S|${XSERVER}|g" /home/${USERN}/.pam_mount.conf.xml
    /bin/sed -i "s|\@P|${XPATH}|g" /home/${USERN}/.pam_mount.conf.xml
fi
```

**Update4**

Placing a whoami in the script, shows than when using su from accounta to accountb, the script is run by accounta.

**Update5**

Using the 'seteuid' option with pam_exec has solved the issue. 
`session optional   pam_exec.so seteuid log=/var/log/pamexec /usr/local/bin/mdrive_add`

whoami now shows 'root' when switching from A to B and there are no permission issues.

I don't understand the terms 'real user ID' and 'effective user ID' in the manual for pam_exec, but that is a question for another day.

> Per default pam_exec.so will execute the external command with the real user ID of the calling process. Specifying this option means the command is run with the effective user ID.

Comment: I gave it a try, and it gives the same error. I'm suspecting that the problem is that it's being executed as accounta, which doesn't have write permission in /home/accountb - butPAM_USER says accountb

Comment: Well there are no errors, but that's because /etc/pam.d/sudo doesn't include common-session (where my stuff is run from).  Also, this would require the user to input the password of accounta rather than accountb.

Comment: I've updated /etc/pam.d/sudo and tried again - it doesn't return the error. With both your commands.

Comment: I've updated my question with the details. I don't see how those variables should affect my sed command.

Comment: I've added it. Replaced passwords and login names etc. with placeholders.

Comment: Whoami shows that accounta is executing the script. Accounta does not have write permission in the folder - and can not have write permission. Can I make root run it somehow?

Comment: Alright, I'm not sure I understand the last comment. When suing from A to B, PAM_USER shows B not A. Anyway, seteuid has done the trick. I don't understand why though. Whoami now shows root and there are no issues. Perhaps I'm just misunderstanding the seteuid description in the manual.

Comment: You're right, in fact I confused myself, it doesn't relate. I saw you found the relevant snippet in the `man` page. Anyway I'm posting a temporary answer with the fix, however I'm still fiddling with the thing and I'll update it once I found the "real" answer. There are differences in the PAM configuration for `su` and (say) `sudo`, so I'm pretty sure it's about that.

Comment: [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12714391/)'s my `/etc/pam.d/su` file; the notable difference between this and `/etc/pam.d/sudo` is the fact that the last two lines don't have an additional `user_readenv=0` which is instead present in `/etc/pam.d/sudo`. Maybe that's the difference, although I wouldn't be able to explain what they do, aside from (vaguely) inhibiting (I guess?) some environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that logging in through `su` `pam_exec` executed the script as the "old" user, which didn't have the permission to write into the "new" user's home directory.

Setting the `seteuid` option in `session optional pam_exec.so log=/var/log/pamexec /usr/local/bin/mdrive_add` made `pam_exec` execute the script as root, which fixed the problem:

```
session optional pam_exec.so seteuid log=/var/log/pamexec /usr/local/bin/mdrive_add
```

However the "real" solution is probably configuring `/etc/pam.d/su` adequately, which is something I'm still fiddling with; I'll update this answer as soon as I understand the right way to configure `/etc/pam.d/su`.